# how to check if the file is changed using stat linux command

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep, openwrt

I want to check if a file is changed or no using stat linux command.

> linux@server:~/$ stat test.txt      File: `test.txt'    Size: 23
>   Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file   Device: 802h/2050d 
>   Inode: 4887765     Links: 1
>
> Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   anis)   Gid: ( 1000/
>   anis)
>
> Access: 2014-07-07 16:34:42.476315578 +0200
>
> Modify: 2014-07-08 12:54:15.756553868 +0200
>
> **Change: 2014-07-08 12:54:15.756553868 +0200**

we can see the time of change.
the purpose is to use this change time to check if the file is modified or no

> linux@server:~/anis$ stat test.txt  |grep Change
>   **Change:  2014-07-08  12:54:15.756553868 +0200**
>
> linux@server:~/anis$ stat test.txt  |grep Change
>
> **Change: 2014-07-08 15:14:03.107977776 +0200**

so how made script running in infinite loop to check if time is changed ?

Comment: Maybe look at `inotify` rather than polling.

Comment: `man inotifywait` and `man inotifywatch`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `stat`.  To simply block until the file is modified, use `inotifywait`:

```
inotifywait -e modify test.txt
```

You may want to wait for a less restrictive set of changes:

```
inotifywait test.txt
```

will block until any event happens on the file.  Also, consider the sanity of your users:

```
inotifywait -qq test.txt
```

Comment: inotifywait run on OpenWrt  ? because inotifyd doesn't work on OpenWrt

Comment: The question is tagged 'linux'.  If you need a solution for an embedded system, that should be specified in the question or the tags.

Comment: in fact in first time I installed inotify on OpenWrt but it doesn't work, so for this reason I look for solution with other tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenWrt Buildroot, then you can select and install inotify-tools during the configuration (make menuconfig, or what ever configuration ui you are using).

After that you can use inotifywait just as William Pursell suggested.

The package *inotify-tools* was added by with [this patch](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2011-July/044682.html) in 2011.